# Limit WP code scope into plugin

Tags: plugins

I am trying to build 2 separate custom plugins for my website when I run into this problem. Both of them are sharing the same kind of a scope, meaning I can't declare a new constant or function with the same name. Is this a known problem and you just have to add prefix? Or is there a better way to move around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, constants are global so they have no scope. Per the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php):

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access
>   constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.

There is an exception to this if you are using a PHP Class. You can then tie the constant to that class.

```
class My_Class
{
    const BLAH = 'This is a Constant';
{
print My_Class::BLAH
```

As for functions they, like constants, are global as well. Per the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be
>   called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice
>   versa.

For example, if I have:

```
function my_func() {
    function my_other_func() {
        // Code
    }

    // More Code
}
```

I can call `my_other_func()` on its own even though it is being defined within `my_func()`.

You can again skirt this using a PHP Class:

```
class My_Class
{
   public function echo_hello_world() {
       $this->echo_hello();
       $this->echo_world();
   }

   private function echo_hello() {
       echo 'Hello ';
   }

   private function echo_world() {
       echo 'World!';
   }
}

$testObj = new My_Class();

$testObj->echo_hello_world();
```

However, if classes are overkill, your best bet is to simply namespace everything by appending something unique in front of the names you are currently using. Usually I will append the textdomain I defined for the plugin/theme so `my_function()` becomes `textdomain_my_function()`.

Comment: I am working my way between switching to OOP or just stick with procedural programming. Might be a good chance to jump over.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I started writing a plugin using procedural programming and it's getting way out of hand so I'm looking to flip it to OOP myself. But anything outside a Class needs to be namespaced though.